# Foreach through a vector containing pointers in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary, vector, iterator

I made a map filled with vectors which looks like this:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<CClass*>> pointers = getMap();
```

And now I want to go through every slot of the map and also through every slot of the vector stored in the map.

This is how it goes through the map:

```
for (std::map<int, std::vector<CClass*>>::iterator it = pointers.begin(); it != pointers.end(); it++)
```

This works fine and it goes through every object just like I want it to.

But now I want to go through every slot in the vector and I tried it like this:

```
for (std::vector<CClass*>::iterator playerIt = it->second.begin(); playerIt != it->second.end(); playerIt++)
```

If I want to access the value stored in it the compiler gives me this error:

```
file.cpp(552) : error C2839: Ungültiger Rückgabetyp 'CClass **' für überladenen Operator '->'
```

Which means "invalid return-type 'CClass **' for overweight operator '->'

regards

Comment: Provided code compiles just fine. Error is somewhere else. See http://ideone.com/Ma2Fda

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but the correct translation for "Überladenen Operator" is "overloaded operator" (at least in a C++ context).

Comment: @JamesKanze I was kind of chuckling at the thought of an "overweight" operator. Like it was written in bold font or something :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playerIt` is an iterator, not a pointer to a `CClass`. You need to dereference the iterator to get a pointer to `CClass`:

```
CClass * player = (*playerIt);
player->ClassMethod(...); // or whatever
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use range-based for loops in C++11 to handle this more readably

```
for (auto& element : pointers)
{
    for (auto& player : element.second)
    {
        // player will be a CClass* that you can use
        std::string name = player->GetName();  // For example
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`playerIt` is an iterator that returns a `CClass*`, but you dereference the iterator via operator->, so you need to dereference the pointer that is returned by the iterator.

So you are possibly saying `playerIt->cclass_method()` when you should be saying `(*playerIt)->cclass_method();`

Of course, storing shared_ptr<>, or unique_ptr objects in your vector might be better and easier to understand, along with using typedef to alias the vector<> part of the map.